# Cyclotomic fields and valuation.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Consider $L=\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]$ the $p^n$-th cyclotomic field. The ideal above $p$ is generated by $\pi_L=1-\zeta$. My question is: how can I compute the following valuation:

$$ v_{\pi_L}(1-\zeta^{a-1})$$

with $(a,p)=1$? Sorry if it is a silly question, but I am trying from hours to find a value.

Comment: You simply need to check how many times is $1-\zeta^{a-1}$ divisible by $1-\zeta$

Comment: I know, do you know a fast way to compute this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: this answer addresses the case $n=1$.

If $a\equiv 1$ (mod $p$) then $1-\zeta^{a-1}=0$. Otherwise $b=a-1$ will be prime to $p$.

It turns out that if $(b,p)=1$ then $1-\zeta$ and $1-\zeta^b$ are associates. Indeed, we have
$$ \frac{1-\zeta^b}{1-\zeta}=1+\zeta+\dots+\zeta^{b-1}\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$$
and since $(b,p)=1$ there is an integer $c$ such that $bc\equiv 1$ (mod $p$), hence
$$ \frac{1-\zeta}{1-\zeta^b}=\frac{1-\zeta^{bc}}{1-\zeta^b}=1+\zeta^b+\dots+\zeta^{b(c-1)}\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$$

Therefore $1-\zeta^b=u(1-\zeta)$ for a unit $u$, so $v_{\pi_{L}}(1-\zeta^b)=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. From this seems I have some problem with the higher ramification subgroup. I mean, a $\sigma$ in the Galois group lives in the $k$-th ramification group if and only if $v_{\pi_L}(\zeta-\sigma(\zeta))=v_{\pi_L}(\zeta-\zeta^a)= \geq k$. But probably I remembered bad that $v_{\pi_L}(\zeta)=0$ and so I don't have the equality $v_{\pi_L}(\zeta-\zeta^a)=v_{\pi_L}(1-\zeta^{a-1})$. Otherwise seems that I have only the first group and no other.

Comment: It might be worth asking a separate question about that. I don't remember much about the higher ramification groups.

Comment: Just one thing, can you confirm me that $v_{\pi_L}(\zeta)=0$?

Comment: Yes, any unit has valuation zero.

Comment: It is late and usually is better don't write while I am tired but: if  I take $a=p+1$ then $1-\zeta^p$ is not zero because $\zeta$ is a primitive $p^n$-th root of unity.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the $n$ before. Everything is fine as long as $a-1$ is invertible mod $p^n$, but otherwise things will be more complicated.

Comment: I know, the problem is I need to find an answer to the general case. But thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

For a general $n$. I call $\zeta_{p^k}$ the $p^k$-th roots of unity.

Take $(a,p^n)=1$ we have:

$$ \begin{cases}
1-\zeta_{p^n}^{a-1}=0 & \ \ \text{if} \ \ a\equiv 1 \ \ (\mathrm{mod} \: p^n) \\
1-\zeta_{p^n}^{a-1}=u(1-\zeta_{p^n}), \ u\in\left(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p^n}]\right)^{\times}  & \ \ \text{if} \ \ (a-1,p^n)=1 \\
1-\zeta_{p^n}^{a-1}=1-\zeta_{p^{n-t}}^s=u(1-\zeta_{p^{n-t}}) & \ \ \text{if} \ \ a-1\equiv 0 \ \ (\mathrm{mod} \: p^t) 
\end{cases}$$

with $1\leq t\leq n-1, \: (s,p^t)=1,\:u\in\left(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p^n}]\right)^{\times}$. We have obtained the equality in the second and third case using the reasonament of carmichael561. In the first case valuation is $\infty$, in the second we have

$$  v_{\pi}\left(1-\zeta_{p^n}^{a-1}\right)=v_{\pi}\left(1-\zeta_{p^n}\right)=1$$

For the third notice that for every $t$ we have the Galois extension $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p^n}]/\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p^{n-t}}]$ with degree $[\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p^n}]:\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p^{n-t}}]]=p^{t}$. We have just one prime ideal $P$ above $p$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p^{n-t}}]$, since $p$ totally ramify in $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p^n}]$. In particular $P$ is generated by $1-\zeta_{p^{n-t}}$. Again, since $p$ totally ramify in the big extension also  $1-\zeta_{p^{n-t}}$ totally ramify in $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p^n}]$.  The ideal above $p$ in large extension is generated by $\pi=1-\zeta_{p^n}$ so we have

$$ (1-\zeta_{p^{n-t}})\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p^n}]=(\pi)^{p^{t}}$$

Therefore

$$ v_{\pi}(1-\zeta_{p^{n-t}})= p^{t} $$