# Absolute Value in Cyclotomic Fields

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

In cyclotomic fields, how does one define the generalised notion of absolute value?

For context, in $\mathbb{C}$ the relationship between the field norm and the absolute value is simply $|z| = \sqrt{\prod_{i=1}^2\sigma_i(z)}=\sqrt{z \sigma(z)} = \sqrt{z\bar{z}}$ where $\sigma$ is the only non-trivial Galois map of the extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ corresponding to complex conjugation.

From this, I would hazard a guess that in the $n^{th}$-cyclotomic field (as there maybe more that one Galois map corresponding to a complex conjugation), we could define the absolute value to be $|\alpha| = \sqrt[k]{\prod_{i=1}^k \sigma_i (\alpha)}$ where $k = |\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})|$. Could someone clarify this, or offer an accepted definition.

Comment: An absolute value extending the usual one on $\mathbb{Q}$ will be $|\sigma(\alpha)|$ where $\sigma$ is an embedding $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta) \to \mathbb{C}$ (ie. since it is a Galois extension $\sigma \in Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})$) and $|.|$ the absolute value on $\mathbb{C}$. Now what you wrote is related to the field norm $N_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)=\prod_{\sigma \in Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})} \sigma(\alpha)$ an homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)^* \to \mathbb{Q}^*$

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: As such there is not just one single absolute value on a number field $K$; there are many of them. In the case of $K=\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$, it turns out that there are $\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}$ good candidates, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. Read ahead for details.

Let $K$ be a number field of degree $n$. We denote by $r_1$ the number of real embeddings of $K$, i.e. non-zero homomorphisms $\sigma_i:K\to \mathbb R$ and by $2r_2$, the number of complex embeddings, $\tau_j:K\to \mathbb C$ such that the image is not entirely real. There are always an even number of complex embeddings because we can compose such a map with complex conjugation to get a different one.

> Then $n=r_1+2r_2$.

So with each embedding, you can use the usual notion of absolute value you are used to (in either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ accordingly) to get $r_1+r_2$ different absolute values on $K$.

Why only $r_1+r_2$ absolute values even though there are $r_1+2r_2$ embeddings? Because the pairs of complex places that only differ by complex-conjugation give the same absolute value because any complex number $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ have the same absolute value $a^2+b^2$.

So to answer the question in your special case, notice that to embed our abstract $K=\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ into $\mathbb C$, there are $\phi(n)$  primitive $n$-th roots of unity in $\mathbb C$ that our abstract $\zeta_n$ can map to and these all define and determine an embedding. So there are $\frac{varphi(n)}{2}$ such choices.

These $r_1+r_2$ absolute values are sometimes called the infinite places of $K$ or the infinite primes of $K$.

This terminology is used because, for every prime $\mathfrak p$ of $O_K$ the ring of integers of $K$, you can define an absolute value first for $\alpha \in O_K$. This is how it goes. First define the $\mathfrak p$-adic valuation of $\alpha$ by $$v_{\mathfrak p}(\alpha )= \sup_{n}\{n|\alpha\in \mathfrak p^n\}$$  and use this to define an absolute value on $O_K$ by $$|\alpha|_{\mathfrak p}=2^{-v_{\mathfrak p}(\alpha)} .$$

Then you can extend this to $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\in K$ with $\alpha, \beta \in O_K$ by $v_{\mathfrak p}(\frac{\alpha}{\beta})=v_{\mathfrak p}(\alpha)-v_{\mathfrak p}(\beta)$. The $2$ used in the definition doesn't really matter. Any real number $a>1$ can be used in it's stead will yield equivalent absolute values (in the sense that they yield the same topology on $K$).

But now I'm getting ahead of myself and if I don't stop this will turn into a course in Algebraic Number Theory.

Comment: Okay so just to clarify by way of example: for $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, such that $\alpha = a_0 + a_1 \zeta_n +..+a_k \zeta^k$, where $k = \varphi(n)$, (I take you to mean) we can define $|\sigma_i (\alpha)| = \sqrt{\sigma_i (\alpha) \sigma_j (\bar \alpha)|} = \sqrt{\sigma_i(a_0 + a_1 \zeta_n +..+a_k \zeta^k)\sigma_i(a_0 - a_1 \zeta_n -..-a_k \zeta^k)}$ for each $\sigma_i \in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})$?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to state at first that I am not major in number theory.
If there is any mistake in this answer, please straightly edit this or devote me if this answer is incurable.

This answer is just a mixture by two materials by some people, where the first part is an addendum for Mr. Ravi's answer, the second part is an example, and we will only talk about $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{m})$ rather than replacing $\mathbb{Q}$ by other fields.

Admit the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{r}q^{s}})=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{r}})\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{q^{s}})$; $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)}=\mathbb{Z}(\zeta);$ $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}]=\phi(p^{r}).$

(1) $\bf{Claim}$ For $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$, 
$(1-\zeta)\mathbb{Z}(\zeta)$ is the unique prime ideal over $p.$

Proof $\text{ }$ By $\mathbb{Z}(\zeta)/(1-\zeta)=\mathbb{Z},$ $(1-\zeta)\mathbb{Z}(\zeta)$ is a prime ideal. It is totally ramified over $p$. To see this, we prove
$$(1-\zeta)^{\phi(p^{r})}\mathbb{Z}(\zeta)=p\mathbb{Z}(\zeta).$$

The LHS equals to
$\prod_{i=1}^{\phi(p^{r})}(1-\zeta)(\sum_{j=1}^{s_{i}-1}\zeta^{j})\mathbb{Z}(\zeta)=\prod_{i=1}^{\phi(p^{r})}(1-\zeta_{i})\mathbb{Z}(\zeta)$ with $\zeta_{i}$ being all $p^{r}$-th primitive roots of unit and $s_{i}$ s.t. $\zeta_{i}=\zeta^{s_{i}},$ with
$\frac{1-\zeta_{i}}{1-\zeta}=\sum_{j=1}^{s_{i}-1}\zeta^{j}\in \mathbb{Z}(\zeta).$

In fact $\prod_{i=1}^{\phi(p^{r})}(1-\zeta_{i})=\Phi_{p^{r}}(1)$ with $\Phi_{p^{r}}$ the cyclotomic polynomial

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)

and thus this equals to RHS. 
This proof is finished because we already know $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}]=\phi(p^{r}),$ which means the ramification index is the degree of extension.
Q.E.D.

(2)Applying the material written by Ravi, someone could see the calculations by Mr.carmichael561 in [Cyclotomic fields and valuation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027694/cyclotomic-fields-and-valuation)
are reasonable.